# A simple lp inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Suppose $f : \mathbf R\rightarrow\mathbf R$ is in $L^p$ for some $p>1$ and also in $L^1$. Show that $\exists c>0$ and $\alpha\in(0,1)$ such that

$$\int_A|f(x)| \, dx\leq c m(A)^\alpha$$

where $m$ is Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Hint: use Holder's inequality

Comment: I don't see how to. I don't have that $f\in L^q$ where $q$ is conjugate to $p$.

Comment: You can write $|f| = |f|*1...$

Comment: lmao ridiculous, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_A |f|\,dx\leq\|f\|_{L^p(A)} \|1\|_{L^q(A)}=\|f\|_{L^p(A)} m(A)^{1/q}\leq\|f\|_{L^p(\mathbf R)}m(A)^{1/q}\quad\blacksquare$$

Comment: It should be $m(A)^{\frac{1}{q}}$, not $m(A)^q$. And don't call it idiotic--it may be simple, but there's nothing wrong or stupid about not seeing it at first. Most things are easy once you know the answer :P